# Nested List with Counters and Flush-Left Labels

Tags: lists

Presently, I accomplish this with a combination of three user-defined lists.  Two of these (`examlist` for single-digit labels, and `exxamlist` for double-digit labels) control the top-level items.  The third (`examlistii`) controls the sub-level items for both of the top-level cases.

The effect (as demonstrated below) is precisely what I want.  The means, though, seems barbaric.  I'd like to accomplish this using a "single" list, perhaps using the 'enumitem' package, but I can't seem to turn the trick with the list keys.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

%examlist
\newcounter{exami}
\newenvironment{examlist}
{\begin{list}{\arabic{exami}.\hfill}
{\usecounter{exami}
\setlength{\labelwidth}{3ex}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0ex}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{3ex}}}
{\end{list}}

%exxamlist
\newcounter{exxam}
\newenvironment{exxamlist}
{\begin{list}{\arabic{exxam}.\hfill}
{\usecounter{exxam}\setcounter{exxam}{9}
\setlength{\labelwidth}{4.2ex}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0ex}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{4.2ex}}}
{\end{list}}

%examlistii
\newcounter{examii} 
\newenvironment{examlistii}
{\begin{list}{\alph{examii})\hfill}
{\usecounter{examii}
\setlength{\labelwidth}{3ex} 
\setlength{\labelsep}{0ex}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{3ex}}}
{\end{list}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
This is the surrounding text. The following list has flush-left labels.   

\begin{examlist}
  \item Problem 1
  \item Problem 2

  \begin{examlistii}
    \item Part (a)
    \item Part (b)
  \end{examlistii}

  \item Problem 3
\end{examlist}

\begin{exxamlist}
  \item Problem 10

  \begin{examlistii}
    \item Part (a)
    \item Part (b)
  \end{examlistii}

  \item Problem 11
\end{exxamlist}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your lists with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%examlist
\newlist{examlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[examlist,1]{
  align=left,
  labelwidth=1.5em,
  labelsep=0pt,
  leftmargin=1.5em,
  label=\arabic*.,
}
\newlist{exxamlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exxamlist,1]{
  align=left,
  labelwidth=2em,
  labelsep=0pt,
  leftmargin=2em,
  label=\arabic*.,
  before=\setcounter{exxamlisti}{9},
}

%examlistii
\newlist{examlistii}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[examlistii,1]{
  align=left,
  labelwidth=1.5em,
  labelsep=0pt,
  leftmargin=1.5em,
  label=\alph*),
  nosep,
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
This is the surrounding text. The following list has flush-left labels.   

\begin{examlist}
  \item Problem 1
  \item Problem 2

  \begin{examlistii}
    \item Part (a)
    \item Part (b)
  \end{examlistii}

  \item Problem 3
\end{examlist}

\begin{exxamlist}
  \item Problem 10

  \begin{examlistii}
    \item Part (a)
    \item Part (b)
  \end{examlistii}

  \item Problem 11
\end{exxamlist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I only changed the ex units into em, which is preferable for horizontal measures. A digit usually is 0.5em wide.

You can get the work with just one environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{examlist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[examlist,1]{
  align=left,
  labelwidth=2em,
  labelsep=0pt,
  leftmargin=2em,
  label=\protect\makebox[1em][r]{\arabic*}.,
  ref=\arabic*,
}
\setlist[examlist,2]{
  align=left,
  labelwidth=2em,
  labelsep=0pt,
  leftmargin=2em,
  label=\alph*),
  nosep,
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
This is the surrounding text. The following list has flush-left labels.   

\begin{examlist}
  \item Problem 1
  \item Problem 2

  \begin{examlist}
    \item Part (a)
    \item Part (b)
  \end{examlist}

  \item Problem 3
\end{examlist}

\begin{examlist}\setcounter{examlisti}{8}
  \item Problem 9 

  \item Problem 10

  \begin{examlist}
    \item Part (a)
    \item Part (b)
  \end{examlist}

  \item Problem 11
\end{examlist}
\end{document}
```

The problem are lists with less than nine items. One can think to a mechanism that checks whether a given list has more than nine items and (at the next pass) adjusts the parameters to take care of this. But this would make different lists of problems, maybe even on facing pages.

Here's the result where in the final environment the numbering has been made to start from 9 to show the effect.

[image]

For completeness, here's the solution where lists with less than nine items have the number flush left, while for lists with more than nine items, only the two digit figures are flush left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,refcount}

\makeatletter
\newlist{xexamlist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[xexamlist,1]{
  align=left,
  labelwidth=\examlist@margin,
  labelsep=0pt,
  leftmargin=\examlist@margin,
  label=\protect\makebox[\examlist@label][r]{\arabic*}.,
  ref=\arabic*,
}
\setlist[xexamlist,2]{
  align=left,
  labelwidth=2em,
  labelsep=0pt,
  leftmargin=2em,
  label=\alph*),
  nosep,
}

\newif\if@examlist
\newcounter{count@examlist}
\newenvironment{examlist}
 {\if@examlist
    \@examlistfalse
  \else
    \setup@examlist\@examlisttrue
  \fi
  \xexamlist}
 {\if@examlist\else
    \edef\@currentlabel{\the\value{xexamlisti}}%
    \label{examlist@@@\thecount@examlist}%
  \fi
  \endxexamlist}
\def\setup@examlist{%
  \stepcounter{count@examlist}%
  \ifnum\getrefnumber{examlist@@@\thecount@examlist}>9
    \def\examlist@margin{2em}%
    \def\examlist@label{1em}%
  \else
    \def\examlist@margin{1.5em}%
    \def\examlist@label{.5em}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
This is the surrounding text. The following list has flush-left labels.   

\begin{examlist}
  \item Problem 1
  \item Problem 2

  \begin{examlist}
    \item Part (a)
    \item Part (b)
  \end{examlist}

  \item Problem 3
\end{examlist}

\begin{examlist}\setcounter{xexamlisti}{8}
  \item Problem 9

  \item Problem 10

  \begin{examlist}
    \item Part (a)
    \item Part (b)
  \end{examlist}

  \item Problem 11
\end{examlist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: egreg, this produces the desired effect, but I was hoping to accomplish it with a "single" list, which I didn't really make clear in my original post. Let me edit my question.

Comment: @steven_nevets You don't want that the one digit numbers are flush left, at least when the list has more than nine items. But in my opinion the lists should be the same across the document, so you have not much choice, have you?

Comment: Hi egreg.  For reasons that I don't want to bore you with, I require ALL labels (single-digit, double-digit, top-level, and sub-level) to be flush left. I'd hoped to accomplish this with a single list, and your and Werner's solutions demonstrate that this is not a trivial exercise.  Ultimately, I think I shall select your original solution (using multiple lists) as my preferred approach.  Thank you for your thoughtful and expert attention to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) can do this in a jiffy. The two nested lists can be modified globally using

```
\usepackage{enumitem,showframe}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{
  label={\arabic*.},
  ref={\arabic*},
  labelindent=0pt,
  widest={10.},
  leftmargin=*,
  align=left}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
  label={\alph*)}, 
  ref={\alph*}}
```

This sets the first `enumerate` level numbering/label (and reference, if needed) to be `\arabic.`, while the second level is `\alph)`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,showframe}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{
  label={\arabic*.},
  ref={\arabic*},
  labelindent=0pt,
  widest={10.},
  leftmargin=*,
  align=left}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
  label={\alph*)}, 
  ref={\alph*}}

\begin{document}
This is the surrounding text. The following list has flush-left labels.   

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Problem~1

  \item Problem~2

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Part~(a)

    \item Part~(b)
  \end{enumerate}

  \item Problem~3

  \setcounter{enumi}{9}% Just for this example

  \item Problem~10

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Part~(a)

    \item Part~(b)
  \end{enumerate}

  \item Problem~11
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

You can also create your own list names using `\newlist`. See the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for more information.

---

It's really unnecessary (in my opinion) to have varying indentations. Here's one way of achieving that though:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,showframe}
\newlist{exami}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exami,1]{
  label={\arabic*.},
  ref={\arabic*},
  labelindent=0pt,
  widest={9.},
  leftmargin=*,
  align=left}
\newlist{examii}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[examii,1]{
  label={\alph*)}, 
  ref={\alph*}}

\newlength{\indentdiff}
\setlength{\indentdiff}{1.2ex}

\makeatletter
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@enumctr}{examii}=0
    \ifnum\value{examii}<9
      \olditem
    \else
      \end{exami}
      \begin{exami}[widest={10.}, start=10]
        \olditem
        \let\item\olditem
    \fi
  \else
    \olditem
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is the surrounding text. The following list has flush-left labels.   

\begin{exami}
  \item Problem~1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce 
  dictum lacus velit, et malesuada enim fringilla eget. Nulla id sem eget odio fringilla 
  ornare ac non urna. Phasellus id sem tincidunt, posuere ante sed, efficitur risus. 
  Phasellus sagittis augue non diam lacinia volutpat. Duis tempus arcu nec arcu porttitor, 
  sit amet gravida velit pretium.

  \item Problem~2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce 
  dictum lacus velit, et malesuada enim fringilla eget. Nulla id sem eget odio fringilla 
  ornare ac non urna. Phasellus id sem tincidunt, posuere ante sed, efficitur risus. 
  Phasellus sagittis augue non diam lacinia volutpat. Duis tempus arcu nec arcu porttitor, 
  sit amet gravida velit pretium.

  \begin{examii}
    \item Part~(a)

    \item Part~(b)
  \end{examii}

  \item Problem~3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce 
  dictum lacus velit, et malesuada enim fringilla eget. Nulla id sem eget odio fringilla 
  ornare ac non urna. Phasellus id sem tincidunt, posuere ante sed, efficitur risus. 
  Phasellus sagittis augue non diam lacinia volutpat. Duis tempus arcu nec arcu porttitor, 
  sit amet gravida velit pretium.

  \setcounter{examii}{9}% Just for this example

  \item Problem~10 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce 
  dictum lacus velit, et malesuada enim fringilla eget. Nulla id sem eget odio fringilla 
  ornare ac non urna. Phasellus id sem tincidunt, posuere ante sed, efficitur risus. 
  Phasellus sagittis augue non diam lacinia volutpat. Duis tempus arcu nec arcu porttitor, 
  sit amet gravida velit pretium.

  \begin{examii}
    \item Part~(a)

    \item Part~(b)
  \end{examii}

  \item Problem~11 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce 
  dictum lacus velit, et malesuada enim fringilla eget. Nulla id sem eget odio fringilla 
  ornare ac non urna. Phasellus id sem tincidunt, posuere ante sed, efficitur risus. 
  Phasellus sagittis augue non diam lacinia volutpat. Duis tempus arcu nec arcu porttitor, 
  sit amet gravida velit pretium.
\end{exami}
\end{document}
```

The idea behind *this* solution is to redefine `\item` to close down the existing `exami` environment and restart a new one with slightly different parameters (`widest={10.}` and `start=10`) before self-redefining to the original `\item` (`\olditem`).

Here is a pseudo-code representation of the redefinition of `\item`:

```
We will need the current definition of \item later, so 
  make a duplicate of \item and store it in \olditem (\let\olditem\item)
With a copy stored, change \item to now do the following:
  if (the enumeration counter being used is "examii") then
    if (the value of counter "examii" < 9) then
      \olditem (remember, this is the original definition of \item that we stored)
    else
      end environment exami (\end{exami})
      begin environment exami (\begin{exami}) with parameters
          that will start at 10 (start = 10); and
          that will only be as wide as "10." (widest = {10.})
        \olditem (the original definition of \item that we stored)
        Immediately reset \item to what it was before (completely destroying this new 
          redefinition since it is no longer needed)
    end if
  else
    \olditem (the original definition of \item that we stored)
  end if
```

Note that we check whether we're using the enumeration counter `examii` even though we're in environment `exami`. That's because `exami` is a regular `enumerate`-like environment (because of `\newlist{exami}{enumerate}{1}`) and `enumerate`-like environment `<list>` is automatically assigned a level 1 counter called `<list>i`; a level 2 counter called `<list>ii`; ... with a lowercase Roman suffix indicating the level counter.

Comment: Werner, this looked promising, but the labels are not ALL flush-left as I require - the single-digit labels float right in your example.  Please see my MWI to see the desired effect.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @steven_nevets: See the updated answer. I've added the `align=left` key to the list of other keys for level `1` in `enumerate`.

Comment: This is close, but the space between the single-digit labels and items is larger than the space between the double-digit labels and items.  I'd like the space to be the same as in my MWI.  This results in two different left-margins, of course, but that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'd also like the 2nd level labels to be flush left with the text of their parent items.

Comment: @steven_nevets: See my updated answer.

Comment: Werner, that is an amazing solution!  While I selected egreg's solution as my preferred approach, I want to acknowledge that your solution alone accomplishes exactly what I asked for, and it is no fault of yours that I don't understand much of your code.  Thank you for your thoughtful and expert attention to my problem.

Comment: @steven_nevets: Why is egreg's the preferred approach? He doesn't achieve what you're after, as far as I can see. Moreover, my approach uses a single environment with an automated adjustment for the items, so from an end-user's perspective, it should be very simple to use.

Comment: Hi Werner.  This is actually a big decision for me as the list will serve as the basis of well over 100 handouts for my math classes.  My only reservation with your excellent solution is that I don't entirely understand the code, and might fight it difficult to modify as circumstances may require (again, no fault of yours).  But I am still considering it.  For the moment, I chose egreg's original three-list solution because I understand it, and I want to be a responsible forum member.  I wish I could show you an example of my handouts for your consideration.  Thanks again.

Comment: @steven_nevets: I'll add some explanation later. You're only referring to my updated answer's `\item`. Perhaps I'll write up a pseudo-code reference so it's a little more clear.

Comment: That is a generous offer, Werner.  Thank you.